# Crazy Jquery ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple Jquery function here:

```
function submit_selection(del,submit)
{
    del='yes';
    submit=true;
    var ITAMZ=new Array();
    var count=0;
    if (submit)
        $('input[group="Blaaa"]:checked').each (function(){
            ITAMZ[count]=$(this).attr('name');
            count+=1;
        });
    $('#s_o_s_r').html('Submitting...');
    $.ajax({
      url: "script/order_select_submit.php",
      context: document.body,
      success: function(data){
        $('#s_o_s_r').html(data);
      },
      error: function()
       {
        $('#s_o_s_r').html('error submitting');
      },
      async:true,
      type: "POST",
      data: {'ITAMZ' : ITAMZ, 'delete': del},
      dataType: "html"
    });
}
```

I swear God, if I trigger it from a href like this:

```
$('#remove_sel').click(function(){
    submit_selection('yes',true);
});
```

It always returns an error, but if I trigger it from a button like this:

```
  $('input.client_btn').click(function(){
var shiiit=$(this).attr('name');
   if (shiiit=='all') document.location.href="order_price.php?show=all";
   else if (shiiit=='selected') {
        ///document.location.href="order_price.php?show=selected";
        submit_selection('yes',true);
        }
   else document.location.href="order_price.php";
});
```

It always triggers a success.
This is rediculous, and I just don't get it.
Plase help... Q.&

Comment: try using fiddler and debug. You will know the error message.

Comment: it doesn't say... it just triggers an error. Could you advice how could I trace what sort of error it is?
It seems it still works, even from a href, but it just triggers an error somewhy...

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but how do I debug the error?

Comment: Lmao, I just figured, if I change 'A HREF' to 'input type=\"button\"' - it works perfectly. But I'm very courios why it wouldn't work for a href??

Comment: PS, also works for an <a> tag without HREF........ WIERD

Comment: k gotta use style=\"text-decoration:underline\" :D roflmao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned a href, and used a SPAN. It was problem with javascript void(0)